# Order mysql table rows by value from generated column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, stored-functions

MYSQL rookie here, so please bear with me.

I have a table called `Cars` that stores data about cars:

- Make
- Model
- MPG
- Price
- number of seats

And I have a table called `priority` that stores how important each car characteristic is to me on a 0-5 scale. So this table might look like:

`+-----+-------+-------+
| MPG | Price | Seats | 
+-----+-------+-------+
|  0  |   2   |  3    |
+-----+-------+-------+`

I want to be able to generate a score for each `Car` like follows:

`score = (car.MPG * priority.MPG) + (car.Price * priority.Price) + (car.seats * priority.seats)`

I want to essentially do a `Select * from cars order by score`. But I'm not sure how to form this query.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
select a.* from cars a, priority b order by ((a.mpg* b.mpg)+(a.price*b.price)+(a.seats*b.seats))
```

Comment: This works great. I was wondering, if my scoring system gets more complicated, is there a way I can store it as a function and just call it somehow?

Comment: Yes...you can create a function
   CREATE FUNCTION `score`(your parameters...(mpg..price...seats... )) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  your scoring system...

  RETURNS the value..
END;...

and your query will call this function..

   select a.*  from cars a order by score(a.mpg,a.price,a.seats)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap the main select into another select which will contain the order clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT c.*, ((c.MPG * priority.MPG) + (c.Price * priority.Price) + (c.seats * priority.seats)) AS score FROM cars) x ORDER BY x.score
```